# how do I get Fixed feature output from Keras CNN layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to get 1 dimentional Fixed outcomes from same Image.
By passing through the Convolution Layer, MaxPooling layer, Flatten Layer in Keras.layers

I don't know it's because of weight of ConvD2 kernel, although I gave a Initializer.Ones()
the weight values are keep changing. what did I missed?

Is there any great idea to get Fixed value from same Image through Keras.layers?

here is my code

```
## get image
img = cv2.imread("puppy.jpg")
resize_img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128))
resize_img = resize_img / 255.0
reshape_img = resize_img.reshape((-1, 128, 128, 3))

## set layers
initializer = tf.keras.initializers.Ones()
conv_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), input_shape=(128, 128, 3), kernel_regularizer=initializer)
polling_layer = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))
flatten_layer = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

## set model
model = Sequential([
    conv_layer,
    polling_layer,
    flatten_layer,
])
model.trainable = False

weight = model.get_weights()
print(weight)
g = model(reshape_img)
print(g)
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "the weight values keep changing"? If you mean it like, your `weight` and `g` variables are different from each other, then it is expected to be. Your weights and model output are not the same thing. Otherwise your `weight` and `g` variable should be the same across different runs.

Comment: You need to be specific, also Conv2D layers have a bias which you did not set to one.